# Help me come up with a witty title for my paper

Tags: academia

My honours thesis is due in soon and I still haven't thought of a great title. I want something that's clever (perhaps using a pun or two), but also gives insight into what I'm doing. Preferably in the form of "Thesis: A Brilliant Thesis" Everyone loves colons.

So what is my thesis about?

It is a statistical dissertation that is exploring the relationships between a number of economic variables and the price of Gold. What I have found is that the last 12 years has destroyed all the relationships between Gold and other factors. It is also worth noting that Gold has been booming in the last ten years.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

The Gold Rush: Modelling the Price of Gold

but it's not great.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language, not stats.

Answer (score 5):

Gold Fitter  (similar to James Bond's, [Gold Finger](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058150/)). You even get a theme song to with your thesis!